# Export csv/xlsx file in laravel vuejs datatable

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, export

I'm having a trouble on how can I implement export file in vue.js using datatable in laravel. I know it is common to ask this problem, but I couldn't find a way yet. When I click button it should automatically download the datatable data in excel. It would be great if anybody could help me out, thank you so much in advance!.

[image]

*I have these two buttons*

```
<button type="button"  @click='togglexl()'>Export xlsx</button> 
<button type="button"  @click='togglecsv()'>Export csv</button>
```

*Vuejs script*

```
export default {
    data(){
        return{
        id: null,
        trip_ticket: null,
        created_at: null,
        status: null,
        status_class: null,
        vehicles: [],
        vehicle_image: null,
        formFields: {
            starting_odo: null,
            ending_odo: null,
            date_submitted_proc: null,
            distance_travelled: null,
            rate_per_km: null,
            flat_rate: null,
            no_nights: null,
            rate_per_night: null,
            remarks: null,
            travel_date: null,
            travel_time: null,
            vehicle_id: null,
            vehicle_name: null,
            status: null,
            total_cost: null
        },
        names: ['starting_odo', 'date_submitted_proc', 'rate_per_km', 'flat_rate', 'travel_date']

        }
    },
    mounted(){
      this.ini();
    },
    methods:{
     ini() {
        $(()=>{
            this.tdatatable().init();
        });
    },
    togglexl(){
      //xlsx file here
    },
    togglecsv(){
      //csv file here
    },
    tdatatable() {
        let vm = this;
        var initTable = () => {
        var table = $('#list-travel-tbl');
            table.DataTable({
                searchDelay: 500,
                scrollX: true,
                scrollCollapse: true,
                processing: true,
                serverSide: true,
                fixedColumns:   {
                    leftColumns: false,
                    rightColumns: 1,
                },
                ajax: {
                    url: BASE_URL + '/tracking/listtravel',
                    type: 'GET'
                },
                columns: [
                    { "data": "id" },
                    { "data": "trip_ticket" },
                    { "data": "company_name" },
                    { "data": "travel_date" },
                    { "data": "starting_odo" },
                    { "data": "ending_odo" },
                    { "data": "date_submit_proc" },
                    { "data": "travelled" },
                    { "data": "po_no" },
                    { "data": "po_amount" },
                    { "data": "rate_per_km" },
                    { "data": "flat_rate" },
                    { "data": "rate_per_night" },
                    { "data": "nights_count" },
                    { "data": "total_cost" },
                    { "data": "is_status" },
                    { "data": "remarks" },
                    { "data": "created_at" },
                    { "data": "id" }
                    
                ],
                columnDefs: [
                    {
                        targets: 1,
                        render: data => {
                            return '<span class="text-nowrap label label-lg font-weight-bold label-light-primary label-inline">'+data+'</span>';
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        targets: [9, 10, 11, 12, 14],
                        render: data => {
                            let values = (data)? toParseNum(data):'';
                            return values;
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        targets: [7, 13],
                        render: data => {
                            let values = (data)? data:'';
                            return values;
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        targets: [13, 16],
                        orderable: false,
                    },
                    {
                        targets: 17,
                        orderable: false,
                        render: data => {
                            return dateTimeEng(data);
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        targets: 15,
                        render: data => {
                            var status = {
                                1: {'title': 'Pending', 'class': ' label-light-warning'},
                                2: {'title': 'Approved', 'class': ' label-light-primary'},
                                3: {'title': 'Completed', 'class': ' label-light-success'},
                            };
                            if (typeof status[data] === 'undefined') {
                                return data;
                            }
                            return '<span class="label text-nowrap label-lg font-weight-bold ' + status[data].class + ' label-inline">' + status[data].title + '</span>';
                        },
                    },
                    {
                        targets: -1,
                        orderable: false,
                        render: data => {
                            return '\
                                <a href="javascript:;" data-id="'+ data +'" class="ml-5 btn-edit btn btn-sm btn-clean btn-icon" title="Edit details">\
                                    <span class="svg-icon svg-icon-md">\
                                        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="24px" height="24px" viewBox="0 0 24 24" version="1.1">\
                                            <g stroke="none" stroke-width="1" fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd">\
                                                <rect x="0" y="0" width="24" height="24"/>\
                                                <path d="M8,17.9148182 L8,5.96685884 C8,5.56391781 8.16211443,5.17792052 8.44982609,4.89581508 L10.965708,2.42895648 C11.5426798,1.86322723 12.4640974,1.85620921 13.0496196,2.41308426 L15.5337377,4.77566479 C15.8314604,5.0588212 16,5.45170806 16,5.86258077 L16,17.9148182 C16,18.7432453 15.3284271,19.4148182 14.5,19.4148182 L9.5,19.4148182 C8.67157288,19.4148182 8,18.7432453 8,17.9148182 Z" fill="#000000" fill-rule="nonzero"\ transform="translate(12.000000, 10.707409) rotate(-135.000000) translate(-12.000000, -10.707409) "/>\
                                                <rect fill="#000000" opacity="0.3" x="5" y="20" width="15" height="2" rx="1"/>\
                                            </g>\
                                        </svg>\
                                    </span>\
                                </a>\
                            ';
                        }
                    }
                ],
                drawCallback: () => {
                    $('.btn-edit').off().on('click', function() {
                        let id = $(this).data('id');
                        vm.show(id);
                    });
                }
            });
        };
        return {
            init: function() {
                initTable();
            },
        };
    },

    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I think this is what you're looking for, just add this inside your vue datatable

Based on documenttion here in datatable https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/examples/initialisation/export.html

```
 dom: 'Bfrtip',
   buttons: 
   ['copy', 'csv', 'excel', 'pdf', 'print'],
```

Answer (score 0):

you can check datatables docs:
https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/examples/initialisation/export.html

Comment: thanks for your response, I already see this, but only problem is how can I apply it into `vue js` laravel

Comment: im not expet in vue, but find how to import and export external js function and u can use the link above